# How to use Number Theoretic Transforms and to prove efficiency O(n log n log log n)?

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields

I am currently researching [Schönhage-Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm) for class. I am using [this article](http://tonjanee.home.xs4all.nl/SSAdescription.pdf) to help me. However, I am stuck on page 13, paragraph 2. I tried a simple example of $x_i = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ but I can't figure out how to proceed after performing the Fourier Transform (by hand) as instructed in the article.

Also, I can't figure out why Schönhage-Strassen algorithm has efficiency of $O(n\log(n)\log(\log(n)))$. Can someone provide me with a proof of it?